# Android Studio Mac auto insert bug

Tags: macos

hello I really like android studio but I have to hit the insert key to be able to type anything code wise! Now this is fine on my Linux box but on my macbook air I do not have a insert key is there a way to disable auto insert in android studio for mac?

Thanks way in advance

Chris

Comment: Fn+Return is the Mac equivalent of Insert.

Comment: @323go: please submit this as an answer instead of a comment so that it can be accepted and this question can be put to bed.

Comment: Done, but it feels like a cheap answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Fn+Return is the Mac equivalent of Insert.